# Updating the nameserver to my website domains fails even with IP address

Tags: domains, dns, dns-servers

I'm not sure what's going on. Basically, I have a large number of domains using the same nameservers: dns1.example.com and dns2.example.com.

Every individual domain name is registered with dotster.com

For example.com, I tried replacing:

```
ns1.dotster-expired.domainparkingserver.net
ns2.dotster-expired.domainparkingserver.net
```

with the IP address of the dedicated server computer that has all the domain records.

I get this message:

> Records for example.com could not be updated. The nameserver you chose may not be a valid nameserver. Please verify with the provider and try again

All domains in question are current (not expired), and I just locked the domain not long ago.

I even verified that the IP address I entered for the computer is correct via my dedicated server control panel, and the WHM installed on the computer. I also verified the IP address is correct because it functioned as expected when I entered it into the web browser.

What I did notice around the time I (attempted) to make changes to the example.com DNS settings is that on the computer with WHM, the IP for example.com DNS has changed to some other IP address. I put that IP address in a browser and reached http://universalfwding.com/.

I understand with DNS changes that I need to wait 24 hours for updates, but is it just the dotster interface being dumb or do I need to do something else with a domain in my dotster account before having the ability to change nameserver domain addresses?

**UPDATE**

I put in dns1.example.com and dns2.example.com as the nameservers on the first attempt and it seemed to work, but the IP addresses don't work. I don't get why when the IP addresses are the ones to the dedicated server.

Comment: I have found that at some places you _have_ to use the FQDN and others you _have_ to use IP address.  Sometimes they auto convert FQDN to IP address, some places don't.  Seems to be individual system quirks

Comment: did you ask dotster ? you pay them for a service, so they have some kind of support, no ?

Answer (score 1):

whois found some answers I need and maybe so did time.

It seems that I need to use dns1.example.com and dns2.example.com as nameservers.

When I looked at the whois records for each of them from my home computer, it pointed directly to the dedicated computer IP address. No IP address however was listed when I looked at whois for example.com but it listed dns1.example.com and dns2.example.com as nameservers.

After such changes, things seemed to work.